# How to implement the fixed length spatial pyramid pooling layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to implement the spatial pyramid pooling layer as introduced [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729v4.pdf).

As the paper setting, the keypoint is to define variant kernel size and stride size of max_pooling layer, which is:

```
kernel_size = ceil(a/n)
stride_size = floor(a/n)
```

where `a` is the input tensor spatial size, and `n` is the pyramid level, i.e. spatial bins of the pooling output.

I try to implement this layer with tensorflow:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def spp_layer(input_, name='SPP_layer'):
    """
    4 level SPP layer.

    spatial bins: [6_6, 3_3, 2_2, 1_1]

    Parameters
    ----------
    input_ : tensor
    name : str

    Returns
    -------
    tensor
    """
    shape = input_.get_shape().as_list()

    with tf.variable_scope(name):

        spp_6_6_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(input_,
                                      ksize=[1,
                                             np.ceil(shape[1]/6).astype(np.int32),
                                             np.ceil(shape[2]/6).astype(np.int32),
                                             1],
                                      strides=[1, shape[1]//6, shape[2]//6, 1],
                                      padding='SAME')
        print('SPP layer level 6:', spp_6_6_pool.get_shape().as_list())

        spp_3_3_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(input_,
                                      ksize=[1,
                                             np.ceil(shape[1]/3).astype(np.int32),
                                             np.ceil(shape[2]/3).astype(np.int32),
                                             1],
                                      strides=[1, shape[1]//3, shape[2]//3, 1],
                                      padding='SAME')
        print('SPP layer level 3:', spp_3_3_pool.get_shape().as_list())

        spp_2_2_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(input_,
                                      ksize=[1,
                                             np.ceil(shape[1]/2).astype(np.int32),
                                             np.ceil(shape[2]/2).astype(np.int32),
                                             1],
                                      strides=[1, shape[1]//2, shape[2]//2, 1],
                                      padding='SAME')
        print('SPP layer level 2:', spp_2_2_pool.get_shape().as_list())

        spp_1_1_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(input_,
                                      ksize=[1,
                                             np.ceil(shape[1]/1).astype(np.int32),
                                             np.ceil(shape[2]/1).astype(np.int32),
                                             1],
                                      strides=[1, shape[1]//1, shape[2]//1, 1],
                                      padding='SAME')
        print('SPP layer level 1:', spp_1_1_pool.get_shape().as_list())

        spp_6_6_pool_flat = tf.reshape(spp_6_6_pool, [shape[0], -1])
        spp_3_3_pool_flat = tf.reshape(spp_3_3_pool, [shape[0], -1])
        spp_2_2_pool_flat = tf.reshape(spp_2_2_pool, [shape[0], -1])
        spp_1_1_pool_flat = tf.reshape(spp_1_1_pool, [shape[0], -1])

        spp_pool = tf.concat(1, [spp_6_6_pool_flat,
                                 spp_3_3_pool_flat,
                                 spp_2_2_pool_flat,
                                 spp_1_1_pool_flat])

    return spp_pool
```

But it cannot gurantee the same length pooling output, when the input sizes are different.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6011

Answer (score 1):

I believe the authors of the paper are wrong, the formula should be:

```
stride_size = floor(a/n)
kernel_size = floor(a/n) + (a mod n)
```

Notice that both formula give the same result for n < 4.
You can prove this result by doing the euclidian division of a by n.

I modified the code I found at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6011 and here it is:

```
def spp_layer(input_, levels=(6, 3, 2, 1), name='SPP_layer'):
    shape = input_.get_shape().as_list()
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        pyramid = []
        for n in levels:

            stride_1 = np.floor(float(shape[1] / n)).astype(np.int32)
            stride_2 = np.floor(float(shape[2] / n)).astype(np.int32)
            ksize_1 = stride_1 + (shape[1] % n)
            ksize_2 = stride_2 + (shape[2] % n)
            pool = tf.nn.max_pool(input_,
                                  ksize=[1, ksize_1, ksize_2, 1],
                                  strides=[1, stride_1, stride_2, 1],
                                  padding='VALID')

            # print("Pool Level {}: shape {}".format(n, pool.get_shape().as_list()))
            pyramid.append(tf.reshape(pool, [shape[0], -1]))
        spp_pool = tf.concat(1, pyramid)
    return spp_pool
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the output size right now is not constant, and looking at your code it seems that your individual pooling operations will have output sizes that alternate between two numbers.  The reason is that the output size, at least for 'SAME', is calculated by the formula

```
out_height = ceil(float(in_height) / float(strides[1]))
```

If for the stride we use what is essentially the floor of in_height/n, then the output will fluctuate between n and n+1.  What you need to do to ensure constancy is use the ceil operation instead for your stride values.  The altered code for spp_6_6 pool would be

```
ksize=[1, np.ceil(shape[1]/6).astype(np.int32), np.ceil(shape[2]/6).astype(np.int32), 1]
spp_6_6_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(input_, ksize=ksize,strides=ksize, padding='SAME')
```

I defined the ksize outside of the call to tf.nn.max_pool() for clarity.  So, if you use your ksize for your strides too, it should work out. If you round up then mathematically as long as the size of the input dimensions are at least double the value of your largest pyramid size n, your output size should be constant with 'SAME' padding!

Somewhat related to your question, in your first max pooling operation your ksize parameter is

```
ksize=[1, np.ceil(shape[1]/6).astype(np.int32), np.ceil(shape[1]/6).astype(np.int32), 1]
```

For the third element of ksize, you did shape[1]/6 instead of shape[2]/6. I assumed that was a typo, so I changed it in the above code.

I'm aware that in the paper that the stride is taken to be the floor of a/n and not the ceil, but as of now, using the native pooling operations of tensorflow, there is no way to make that work as desired.  'VALID' pooling will not result in anything near what you want.

Well... if you're really willing to put the time into it, you can take the input size modulo your largest pyramid dimension, in this case 6, and handle all six of these circumstances independently.  I can't find a good justification for this though.  Tensorflow pads differently than other libraries such as, say, Caffe, so inherently there will be differences.  The above solution will get you what they're aiming for in the paper, a pyramid of pooling layers where disjoint regions of the image are being max-pooled with differing levels of granularity.

EDIT:  Actually, if you use tf.pad() to manually pad the input yourself and create a new input for each max pooling operation such that the new inputs have height and width a neat multiple of n, then it would work out with the code you already have.

Comment: Thank you. I have a test and it also cannot achieve the paper's goal, e.g. `shape = 13, stride=13/6=3, output_size=13/3=5`, but 'shape=16, stride=16/6=3, output_size=16/3=6`