# How to ouput 6 classes with (None,None,3) image size using VGG16

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using VGG16 to train a neural network to identify 3 classes, but I don't have any fixed image size (all I know for an image that is m x n, m,n<300). So I set `input_shape` of the input layer as `(None, None, 3)`. The question is how can I go down to one dimension from 3 dimensions (row, col, channel)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to classify the image then you will have to use fully connected layers which requires fixed image dimension, which can be avoided by using SPATIAL PYRAMID POOLING.

In [spatial pyramid pooling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729.pdf) the input dimension doesn't have to be fixed it can be of any variable dimension .
By adding a new SPP layer on top of the last convolutional layer, before the fully connected layer followed by a softmax layer  will solve the problem.

implementation discussion [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6011), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913794/how-to-implement-the-fixed-length-spatial-pyramid-pooling-layer)